# Fluent Nhibernate memory leak with heap dump attached

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm aware there were previous Nhibernate issues with the query cache posted in 2008.   I'm using Fluent NHibernate 1.4.0 and NHibernate 3.3.1.  I'm running a synchronization program which is opening from multiple sessions and creating multiple queries as I'm dealing with a large dataset.  All of my data structures I'm using terminate and are of generally finite length.  What I've picked up from the CLRProfiler tool is that the class SessionFactoryImpl is growing large.

Here's a memory heap dump of the application

Go to the link at https://app.box.com/s/pvbe9ryfb0v168rka2e3 to see the memory heap dump.

I'm using Stateless Sessions throughout my application and I'm wrapping everything in using blocks.   I've set the my Session Factory creator to have the following lines

```
return Fluently.Configure().Database(cfg).Mappings(m => {
            var fluentMappings = m.FluentMappings;

            fluentMappings.Add<UCBPremMap>();
            fluentMappings.Add<UTVSSFXMap>();
        }).Cache(c => {
            c.Not.UseQueryCache();
            c.Not.UseSecondLevelCache();
        }).BuildSessionFactory();
```

but I think from my interpretation of the heap diagram, the NHibernate cache data structures continue to grow until I run out of memory.

The stack overflow also typically happens when trying to parse another expression tree (I'm trying to minimize database calls and sometimes I can only search fields by content, which creates an expression tree with 1000s of individual where clauses).

Any help will be appreciated.  My coworker, on a different program, had also noticed that his program was hitting OutOfMemory exceptions, which also suggests that there's a memory leak in NHibernate.

Comment: Did you find anything? Was there a leak? I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my post to Google Groups with the same issue.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/LDYlxhUPZuo

I've solved the problem using reflection to access the planCache field in QueryPlanCache and to set the Hashtable to have a content size from 128 to 8.